# Error while saving theme configuration

Tags: magento2, theme

I am trying to update Welcome text in theme configuration, but when i am saving changes it giving me "An error occurred while saving the configuration. Area is already set". I am using meigeeteam's universal theme.

[image]

[image]

Comment: go to the table called "theme" from database  and check the settings

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i found this bug reported in Magento 2.2.4 , I got that from git